# Understanding routing and subnets

Tags: networking, router, routing, subnet

I'm trying to wrap my head around subnets and how hosts communicate between them, but the articles I find usually only focus on calculating the subnet and host IDs rather than how and why to use them.

This is from an [article](https://www.dummies.com/programming/networking/exploring-tcpip-routers/) I found:

[image]

*When someone at address 130.103.2.1 sends e-mail to 130.103.2.4, the router is smart enough to see that the message is staying on the same subnet. There is no need to investigate any routes to the other subnet or to the Internet. When 130.103.2.1 sends e-mail to 130.103.1.4, however, the router forwards the message to the other subnet. When someone from anywhere within the intranet sends a message outside the 130.103 intranet, the router forwards the message out to the Internet.*

I understand that the point here is have two separate networks which in turn reduces congestion, but I can't see why the subnet mask is needed.

My questions are:

- If the router is smart enough to see that the message is staying on the same subnet, why is it important for each host to know its own subnet mask?
- Under which circumstances will a message not be able to reach its intended destination because of segregated subnets/networks?

Comment: Just to emphasize my last edit: The quoted article is **quite misleading** when it implies that only the router makes these decisions. It may, but in practice same-subnet packets _never reach_ the router in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the router is smart enough to see that the message is staying on the same subnet, why is it important for each host to know its own subnet mask?

Simple: Being in a subnet allows hosts to communicate *without the need of a router.*

The article you found is somewhat misleading in implying that a router is always used. In practice that's **not usually true:** Ethernet hosts implement the same 'subnet' logic, therefore same-subnet traffic never even *reaches* the router. (It enters the Ethernet switch from host A, and exits straight to host B.)

That said... Yes, the method you quoted (all hosts sending everything to a router; the router sending to the other host) is completely **possible**, and indeed used in some situations – by ISPs, by datacenters, and generally when direct communications are undesirable.

But it has the significant downside that the router becomes a necessity for the subnet to work, instead of being an optional component that merely acts as a gateway to external networks. Among other things, it's yet another point of failure.

It also turns the router into a performance bottleneck. When hosts are connected to their individual ports of an Ethernet switch, the sum of all traffic going *directly* between ports can be much greater than if it all were squeezed through the router's single port and back.

For example: On a modern 24-port 1 Gbps switch, the total theoretical capacity is 48 Gbps (full-duplex). You can have hosts A and B accessing a NAS storage, hosts C/D/E exchanging peer-to-peer Windows updates, hosts F/G/H streaming a Steam In-Home game, host XXX watching 4K on YouTube, and still plenty of switching capacity remaining.

On the other hand, if a single router were in the middle of everything, pushing everything through that router's port (and back!) would limit the whole network to 1 Gbps in total.

> Under which circumstances will a message not be able to reach its intended destination because of segregated subnets/networks?

When the router refuses to forward the message; e.g. it has the wrong route (or no route at all), or its firewall rules forbid the message. The ability to filter packets via firewall rules is actually one of the main reasons of using subnets.

Note that sometimes the message might reach the destination but the *reply* won't go through, which is an important distinction because routes or firewall rules in both directions can be completely independent.

Comment: I learned a lot from this answer. Thank you!

Comment: So the subnet mask i used to tell us if an IP is inside our own subnet, and if we want to send something to an IP that is outside the subnet it has to go via a gateway (typically a router), but if its inside we can send it directly to the specific host?

Comment: Yes. It informs the hosts whether the possibility of direct communications exists.

Comment: That should be the first sentence of any article on subnets. Thank again.

Answer (score 0):

The subnet mask is important to decide what is on your own network. It's why you have the network ID (think of it as the corporate telephone number) and the host ID (which is your extension) and you need a third party to reach another network ID (some department within your corporation that you'd need to call if you want to talk with someone outside of your corporation).

If you notice you have a network ID that is different to your own you know you won't be able to stay within your own network and send your traffic somewhere else/do routing. Each endpoint (in theory) is capable to be a router which is why everyone needs to implement that mechanism.

A packet won't be able to reach it's destination if there is no path available. For instance if you're on a LAN party without internet even if you know the IP of a google server you won't be able to reach it because there is no physical route to it. A less extreme example would be a network that has three segments and no default routes.

```
A <R1> B <R2> C
```

Unless you setup a route that tells R1 that he can reach hosts with a network ID of C through R2 he wouldn't know what to do if he gets a package that should be send to network C.

Answer (score 0):

It is called a subnet *mask* because it is used to identify the network address of an IP address by performing a bit-wise AND operation on the netmask.

The IPv4 Subnet mask is a 32-bit number that masks the IP address, and divides the IP address into network address and host address. It is made by setting network bits to all "1"s and setting host bits to all "0"s.

The bitwise intersections of all IPv4 addresses in the same network segment
give the same result. If the intersection gives another result,
this means that the address is not in the subnet.

The IP address inside the subnet has two components : the network address and the host address. The subnet mask separates the IP address into the network and host addresses
within the subnet (`<network><host>`).

The "1" bits in the mask are also called the network prefix, and often
the subnet IP address is defined using their number, such as
`1.2.3.0/24`, where the network mask is implied as having 24 bits of "1".